# Open CV cant read an image from URL

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to read an image from an url using open-cv.My code is

```
url = "some url"

            hdr = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
            req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers=hdr)

            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
            image1 = cv2.imread(image)
```

However I get an error like this-
image = cv2.imread(image)
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'numpy.ndarray' to 'str' for 'filename'

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. This will help

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests

url = 'https://i.imgur.com/S3OGqV6.jpeg'
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```